# Firebase Database not writing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to learn how to connect my android application to the firebase database. I've tried the following code:

```
mDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
productCloudEndPoint = mDatabase.child("Sample");
productCloudEndPoint.push().setValue("Hello World");
```

However, nothing gets written when I look at the Firebase console. I have also set the rules.

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: would you try productCloudEndPoint.push().child("value").setValue("Hello World");

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong from this code. Is your logcat showing any relevant warning/error messages?

Comment: Are you trying to execute this code when you are authenticated or not? Also try to change: productCloudEndPoint.push().setValue("Hello World"); to: productCloudEndPoint.setValue("Hello World");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I was using the simulator. You have to use a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use push method when you are using set() method, set() method would set the value to the reference.

ex:

```
<database-ref>/users/{UserId}/
username: {name}
```

Query would be:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);
```

In your case :

```
mDB.child("sample").setValue("Hello World");
```

While push method used to post new custom object, Firebase generates unique id and save into list of such objects.
NOTE: Push() method is used fro javaScript.

**Example :**
You have user object with properties like

```
Class User{
String name;
String email;
}
```

To save such object, you can simply use push() method.
Firebase will save it with a unique Id auto generated.

```
<db-ref>/users/{uniqueId}/
```

**For JAVA: equivalent method is put() method.**